# Avoid Generic Lists in Base Class - Should I Follow the Same Rule for Dictionary?

Tags: c#, list, generics, inheritance, dictionary

I was [advised](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/116538/94214) to change  a `List<string>` property to a `Collection<string>`, in a base class, because it is more appropriate for inheritance.

This 'rule' was referred to: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182142.aspx

> System.Collections.Generic.List is a generic collection that is
>   designed for performance and not inheritance.
>   System.Collections.Generic.List does not contain virtual members
>   that make it easier to change the behavior of an inherited class. The
>   following generic collections are designed for inheritance and should
>   be exposed instead of System.Collections.Generic.List.
>
> ```
> System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection<T>
>
> System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection<T>
>
> System.Collections.ObjectModel.KeyedCollection<TKey, TItem>
> ```

Does a similar rule apply to `Dictionary<string, string>`?

I ask because it is also in the `System.Collections.Generic` namespace. Or maybe I have misunderstood and the rule only applies to `Lists`.

BTW, the `Dictionary` purpose is to hold errors (in a similar format to ModelState). I am not currently sure at exactly what stage I will be adding errors to it.

---

If I ***should*** be avoiding `Dictionary<string, string>` in the base class, what should I be using in it's place?

I have come across `KeyedCollection` but not sure if that is a good replacement.

Comment: Wait a minute. What are you actually trying to achieve? Do you want to inherit from a collection or do you simply want to use the list/dictionary as a property/field in a base class?

Comment: It's a property for holding errors (in a similar format to ModelState errors). I am not currently sure at exactly what stage(s) I will be adding errors to the dictionary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So basically what you were told could potentially be wrong for the use case you are going for.

The statement in the msdn article means by inheritance if you want to create your own implementation of a collection by deriving from it like so:

`public class MyCollection : Collection<MyType>`

The advantage of using `Collection<T>` in this scenario is that you can alter the behavior significantly as it exposes the following methods which can be overriden: `ClearItems`, `InsertItem`, `RemoveItem` and `SetItem`. When you derive from `List<T>` you can't override any methods at all (except for the standard `ToString`, `Equals` and `GetHashCode`).

But as you stated in your comment you use the `List`/`Dictionary`/`Collection` as a property. Therefore it rather depends on your own use case.

If you want deriving classes to just use the collection from the base class you can let it be whatever you think is best suited for your needs. But if you think that the deriving class will know better which collection to use then you should 
pick an interface from the `System.Collections.Generic` namespace.

I won't tell you which types or interfaces you should use when as it heavily depends on which functionality you need.

And by the way: the `KeyedCollection` can only be used to create your own key value collection (it is abstract). Therefore having a `KeyedCollection` as a property would mean that you'd also need an implementaion of a `KeyedCollection`.

Comment: that is very clear and informative - thank you very much!

Answer (score 4):

`Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` does not have any base class you can use instead of it. It may be better to use interface (`IDictionary<TKey, TValue>` or maybe `IReadOnlyDictionary<TKey, TValue>` -both implemented by `Dictionary`), but it depends on your needs.

Note that it is very hard to express whether property returns internal storage or clone (and hence what happens when caller changes object) - you may want to consider `IEnumerable<T>` or methods that hide dictionary as implementation details.